# Using dynamic list of variables to build a pydantic model

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I am using Pydantic to validate data that a customer is sending and could have arbitrary number of variables.

For example, sometimes the data might have 4 columns: `[SKU_type1, SKU_type2, SKU_type3, SKU_type4]`, while other times customer might be send data that could be 6 columns: `[..., SKU_type6]`. The datatype for these columns is "str". Column names will share common elements to make them easy to group in a list.

What might be the best to build a Pydantic model that accommodates the variable number of columns in incoming data?

I have tried using a loop to build a Pydantic model but that just seems wrong.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "columns". Do you mean _fields_, _attributes_ or _keys_? Because a Pydantic model is not a table. Also, can you elaborate a bit, why you think you need Pydantic for this in the first place? If you expect arbitrary keys, why not just use a dictionary? Where does validation come in? Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating your use case.